# How to retrieve the Metadata from nodejs aws s3 getObject callback data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload/download an audio chunk file to/from S3 using AWS node SDK. I have tried base64 approach and it works fine. But I am not able to get the Metadata back which I have bundled as part of upload params.

Below is the code snippet for upload along with meta info:

```
var myMetaInfo = "AdditionalInfo", dataToUpload = {Bucket: bucketName, Key:storageFolderFullPath , Body: myAudioFile.toString('base64'), Metadata: {metaInfo: myMetaInfo}};
s3.client.putObject(dataToUpload, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Successfully uploaded the file to ::" + dataToUpload.Bucket);            
    } else {
        console.log(" **** ERROR while uploading ::"+err);            
    }        
});
```

And this is the snippet for downloading the file. Metadata is not part of the callback data.
    I tried printing the callback 'data' to console and noticed that only the following params are available
    LastModified, ContentType, ContentLength, ETag, Body, RequestId

```
var dataToDownload = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: storageFolderFullPath}, originalFile, myMetaInfo;
s3.client.getObject(dataToDownload, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {            
        originalFile = new Buffer(data.Body, 'base64');
        myMetaInfo = data.Metadata.metaInfo;
        console.log(" Meta info:: " + myMetaInfo);
        fs.writeFile(fileStoragePath, originalFile, function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(" File written!! ");
            } else {
                console.log(" Error while writing the file !!" + err);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log(" **** ERROR while downloading ::"+err);            
    }
});
```

Any pointers on what is wrong with my implementation? I have followed the documentation mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/Client.html#putObject-property)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `metaInfo` value a string?

Referencing the [sdk api docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html), `Metadata` is a string map (ala ~ `Metadata: {metaInfo: "myMetaInfoString"}`. I've tested your code using a string as the value for `metaInfo` and it does return correctly under the `data.Metadata.metaInfo` reference.