# Accessing metadata of video stored in S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded a video file to S3 using their `NodeJS` SDK with some metadata. I can see the metadata on the S3 console.
[image: Metadata visible on S3 console]
I am recording the timestamp of when in the video a particular event occurs to begin playback from that time when someone renders the video.

This timestamp is what I am storing as part of the metadata in the video file so that I do not need to pass this data to the server through another medium.
I need to use this metadata in my Rails application during render.

When I download the video file, the metadata seems to be lost. I tried using `ffprobe` to get all meta content but that data visible in S3 is lost.

[image: metadata not visible using ffprobe]

I read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14629737/2651076) and I seem to be doing the upload right.

---

Is the metadata I see on the console AWS specific?

How do I access that data through my Rails server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "head" operation will allow you to access the metadata without fetching the entire object. Follow this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#head_object-instance_method) for more info.

If I were you I would store the metadata in DynamoDB. It is much easier to play with & makes your app more flexible for the future.

Comment: Great! I could fetch the metadata using the `head` operation. But I am still confused as to why downloading the video without the AWS SDK does not bundle the metadata? Is there no way to access the metadata without the SDK?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the first part of the question, A getObhect call should return the meta data in the response. Try to console.log data.Metadata.